# webservice descriptor file

Tags: web-services, wsdl

is a webservice descriptor file used to inform the webservice container the services that it expects from it ?

Comment: Please be exact in what you're asking? What is the name of the file you're referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you refer to the web service consumer, but anyhow: yes - the WSDL file
is used to describe the message that are exchanged between webservice provider and
consumer.

you might find [this](http://www.service-architecture.com/web-services/articles/web_services_explained.html) worth reading.

Cheers

Comment: i mean the deployment descriptor file. Why is it really being used?